# how to get all elements of an ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview

I need get all elements of ArrayAdapter of an ListView.

Like this:

```
    this.array = new ArrayAdapter<DocumentoDominiabilidade>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    this.documentosDominiabilidade.setAdapter(array);

// after many operations

this.array.getAllElements() // return a List of Elements????
```

thank you

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using `Adapter.getCount()` you can know how many items you have in the adapter, while using `Adapter.getItem(index)` will give you the item.

```
for(int i=0 ; i<adapter.getCount() ; i++){
   Object obj = adapter.getItem(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [JafarKhQ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1124691/jafarkhq)'s answer, here's a one-liner to put them all into a List:

```
IntStream
    .range(0, adapter.getCount())
    .mapToObj(adapter::getItem)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```